# Invalidating Cloudfront Cache in Craft 3

Tags: craft3, aws

We very recently migrated from Craft 2 to Craft 3 and I was wondering what was the easiest way to invalidate Cloudfront's cache?

I saw that Craft 3 has a panel for clearing cache in the `Utilities` menu, within the admin dashboard, but I didn't find any information about if it integrates with the AWS S3 plugin, or similar.

This is the panel I'm refering to:

[image: panel]